# The predicted value of the Sequential model is the same as the input value

Tags: python, keras

We used Keras sequential models to create and run models that predict weather variables
However, the prediction results of the model have the same problem as the input values
We've reduced the number of people hiding, reduced the learning rate, and applied early stopping.
But the problem hasn't been solved
I don't know how to solve it

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

import pandas as pd

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Embedding, LSTM, GRU, Dense, Dropout
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from sklearn import preprocessing

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'T' : df['기온(°C)'],
                    'WS' : df['풍속(m/s)'],
                    'RH' : df['습도(%)'],
                    'P' : df['해면기압(hPa)'],
                    'VS' : df['시정(10m)'],
                    'TD' : df['이슬점온도(°C)']})

wfm.add(Dense(12, input_dim = 6, activation = 'tanh'))
wfm.add(Dense(12, activation = 'tanh'))
wfm.add(Dense(6, activation = 'relu'))
wfm.add(Dense(6, activation = 'relu'))
wfm.add(Dense(6, activation = 'relu'))
wfm.add(Dense(6, activation = 'relu'))
wfm.add(Dense(6, activation = 'relu'))
wfm.add(Dense(6, activation = 'relu'))

wfm.compile(loss = 'mean_squared_logarithmic_error', optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.001))

wfm.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 100, batch_size = 10,
        validation_data = (x_val, y_val))

def predict(data):
  result = wfm.predict(data)

  result = scaler.inverse_transform(data)

  print("1시간 뒤 기상변수 예측")
  print("기온 : ", result[0,0], "degreeC")
  print("풍속 : ", result[0,1], "m/s")
  print("습도 : ", result[0,2], "%")
  print("기압 : ", result[0,3], "hPa")
  print("시정 : ", result[0,4]*10, "m")
  print("이슬점 온도 : ", result[0,5], "degreeC")

  n = pd.DataFrame({'T' : [35.2],
                    'WS' : [0.8],
                    'RH' : [48],
                    'P' : [1004.3],
                    'VS' : [1963],
                    'TD' : [22.5]})

  now = (n - df1.min())/(df1.max() - df1.min())

  predict(now)
```

This is result

```
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 129ms/step
1시간 뒤 기상변수 예측
기온 :  35.2 degreeC
풍속 :  0.8 m/s
습도 :  48.0 %
기압 :  1004.3 hPa
시정 :  19629.999999999996 m
이슬점 온도 :  22.50000000000001 degreeC
```

df1 is normalized to scikit-learn with MinMaxScaler

Comment: Could you include the part where you get `x_train`, `y_train`, `x_val` and `y_val`? I would also suggest making the model way smaller, shallower, and using same activation functions. That way, you could inspect the weights and biases of your trained model more easily.